# Windows 2008 R2 Sysnative Configuration

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have just installed a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise x64 on a VM but i don't see the C:\Windows\Sysnative folder.

DO I need to execute some manual steps to enable the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysnative is a virtual directory not a real one and it only visible from 32 bit applications.  Explorer is 64 bit so you won't see it listed there.

From [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by
>   substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64
>   recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file
>   system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and
>   easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file
>   system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the
>   Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.